# AS3 Camera denied if loaded in a parent SWF

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a child SWF file that has the Camera functionality.
It works fine if I run the child SWF by itself.

However, when I load the child SWF into a parent SWF, the Camera functionality does not work.
Doing some tracing it says that Camera access is denied. That happens without me even clicking on the deny button and in fact the usual security popup does not even show up.

I have added 
import flash.system.Security;
flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");
to both parent and child SWF.

What am I missing?

It's Flash 10 player.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? Cause i am having the same problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out.
In the HTML file, there is this wmode: 'direct'
That screw things up.

Thanks,
Tee